# How to get automatic call back through WMI when things changes on computer?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, wmi, wmi-query

I have installed WMI code create creator from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) and I am wondering what namespace and classes we need to select from application as shown below in an image in order to get an automatic call back in WMI when things changes on computer.

[image]
After getting the right namespace and class, I will generate a C# code from the code language on the menu (as shown above in an image) at the top from the code creator and run it on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI **Events** for this purpose, here are some references:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/monitor-folders-with-wmi-event-subscriptions

It would look something like;

```
  WmiQuery ="Select * From SomeWMIEvent";    
  Watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(Scope, new EventQuery(WmiQuery));
  Watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(this.WmiEventHandler);
```

Comment: thanks. It did help. I am wondering what namespace and class I need to select from the WMI code creator ?

Comment: ...well it depends what you need to monitor? Which things do you want notified of change on?

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner in WMI so that's the only way I know. `I go into the WMI code creator and then I select a specific namespace and class. After selection, I generate a C# code and run it on my computer.`

Any kind of event, like plugging in of USB device, plugging out of USB device, any new installation, any changes in the windows directory and so on.

Comment: Well for USB you can either use Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 or __InstanceDeletionEvent WHERE TargetInstance IS A 'Win32_USBHub'

Comment: Just lookup the WMI documentation, and filter events. It tells you what they all do...